# UITableView crashing on search

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to add a search bar to my UITableView and seem to be crashing while executing this code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath         
   {
    Book *book = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        book = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }

        // Configure the cell.
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // Configure the cell.
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }    
 }
```

the console error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 2 in
>   section at index 0'

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
  // Configure the cell to show the book's title 
  Book *book = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];   
  cell.textLabel.text = book.title; 
}

      - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
 }


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    return [self.searchResults count];
}
else
{

id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

}

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{    
   switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: Whats inside the configureCell function?

Comment: - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    // Configure the cell to show the book's title
    Book *book = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = book.title;
}

Comment: Do you have multiple sections in your tableView?

Comment: Show us code for - numberOfRows and numberOfSections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In configureCell: you have

```
Book *book = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

which is only valid if your not searching, you should pass in Book to configureCell instead of indexPath.

so

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath         
   {
    Book *book = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        book = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }

        // Configure the cell.
        [self configureCell:cell withBook:book];
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        book = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // Configure the cell.
        [self configureCell:cell withBook:book];
        return cell;
    }    
 }

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withBook:(Book *)book { 
  // Configure the cell to show the book's title    
  cell.textLabel.text = book.title; 
}
```